# How to break the REMOTE debugged Linux kernel from the LOCAL machine via GDB + KGDB?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, remote-debugging, kgdb

I'm debugging the Linux kernel through GDB + KGDB + two virtual machines + serial ports.

If we use GDB to debug a normal program, we can just press Ctrl+C to break the execution of the program.

However, when I connect GDB to a remote KGDB stub, I cannot break the remote machine anyway, except that I use the following command on the **REMOTE** machine:

`echo g > /proc/sysrq-trigger`

How to break the **REMOTE** debugged Linux kernel from the **LOCAL** machine?

Comment: The sequence described in https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kgdb/EnableKGDB.html does not work?

Comment: The documentation you cited doesn't tell me how to send the break command from the HOST(!!!) machine rather than from the target machine.

Answer (score 0):

You should use minicom -in the local machine- for the serial connection between both machines: press Ctrl-A and then 'F' (this is for sending a break to the remote machine), and after that send 'G': this is the same as the echo command you mentioned above.